# How to fill nan records in a dataframe with date subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has two columns: Date_created and Date_closed. And if Date_closed is NaN, it means the case is still open.

I want to introduce a new column called Days_to_close, which is the number of days difference between Date_closed and Date_created.

After running the following code:

```
DF['Days_to_close']=DF['Date_Closed']-DF['Date_Created']
```

Pandas returns the Days_to_close for all closed cases, leaving the open cases NaN because Date_Closed is NaN.

Then I want to fill the Days_to_close for those open cases by today's date minus Date_Created, so I wrote this code:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
DF['Days_to_close'].fillna(today- DF['Date_Created'])
```

However, I'm getting the following error message: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'`

I also tried to create a dataframe for today by doing

```
today = datetime.date.today()
todaydf = pd.Dataframe({today})
```

Then the error message changes to: `cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray`

How should I overcome this problem? Do I need to check every NaN record via a loop & if statement and fill each one individually?
Thanks

Comment: First fill nan with todays date, with same format, other dates are, then parse that column by passing parse string. Second parse the second Date Column, then subtract these two columns.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest you fill the NaN values first then calculate the difference after (make sure the dates columns are parsed as datetime).

i am assuming you are reading from a csv, in my example of date parsing, it can be whatever format you are using.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filepath", parse_dates=['Date_Created', 'Date_Closed'])

df['Date_Closed'].fillna(pd.to_datetime("today"), inplace=True)
#df['Date_Closed'] = df['Date_Closed'].fillna(pd.to_datetime("today"), inplace=True)
df['Days_to_close'] = df['Date_Closed']- df['Date_Created']
```

hope this helps.